# Error in gettext() method of edittext

Tags: android-studio, gettext

I have try to develop a login page. But the gettext() method of EditText has produced a run time error with error message

> attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference.

How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Watch the id you gave? Does the id is right? And write your code in question too.

Comment: Always add logcat/error log with your question.